# How can I do classification with categorical data which is not fixed?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data

I have a classification problem with both categorical and numerical data. The problem I'm facing is that my categorical data is not fixed, that means that the new candidate whose label I want to predict may have a new category which was not observed beforehand.

For example, if my categorical data was `sex`, the only possible labels would be `female`, `male` and `other`, no matter what. However, my categorical variable is `city` so it could happen that the person I am trying to predict has a new city that my classifier has never seen.

I am wondering if there is a way to do the classification in these terms or if I should do the training again considering this new categorical data.

Comment: can you convert `city` to a number based on some function? Like `city' = f(latitude, longitude)` that way, you can create a new value for any city

Comment: @MohammadAthar here has given the perfect solution, hope that OP sees it!

Comment: What about using word embedding instead of 1-hot encoding in cases where cardinality of categorical data is huge?

Answer (score 14):

It is very good question; in fact this problem has been around for a while and I have not yet found the perfect solution. Yet more than happy to share my experience:

- **Avoid one-hot-encode** as much as possible (contrary to what was suggested above). The reasoning is that it won't work. A model with one-hot-encode features only works when all those sublevels had been existed in the training data. The model won't be able to do prediction, unless somehow it is manually tweaked. If you search you will find many people ran into this issue when splitting their data into train/test, and faced the issue of some sublevels of a particular feature were not present in the training split and subsequently failed to do prediction on the test. Said aside, if you have very high cardinal features (maybe like your city with let's say 200 city names), this will increase the dimensionality of your data unnecessarily! If for some reasons you may need to do one-hot-encoding, just keep these in mind.
- **Use Other Encoding Methods**. Maybe try learning more about other methods that are robust to this issue, at least for the time being like target-based coding, hashing (see some references below). If you are with Python there is a nice [package](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/categorical-encoding) offer mant encoding options. You may be surprised to see that other simple methods often works just fine.
- **Retrain your model**. Theoretically when learning your train/set should have had the same distribution (mostly this is thought of as target distribution, but can be true about variables as well). Now with new items comes into play, your test (unseen) data distribution has changed. Then it is best to **retrain** the model again so that those new cities will be accounted for.
- **Put Newly Added Subcategories (and least frequent ones) to *Others***. While earlier point is true theoretically, it is very likely that the test distribution (of that particular category) won't change that drastically in most of the cases e.g. very few items goes top of the categories in the training set. Perhaps like in your case, you may have 100 cities in the city feature, and just very few new ones comes over time. What I would consider would be looking at the let's X-quantile of that particular category, and put the least frequent ones into **Others** subcategory. Assuming your newly added data point is only little, it will very much goes into the **Others** group. You will certainly lose a level of granularity by doing this one, but once again the point of learning is that not only your model learn the training data, but most importantly to be able to generalize very well on unseen data and if those new added categories are very data points, grouping them altogether into the **Others** group won't hurt.
- **Other Recent Not-Yet Mature Solutions** like **Cat2Vec (borrowed from Word2Vec from NLP)** or **Similarity Encoding**. These are very recent, check the [paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=HyNxRZ9xg) for the former and its [github](https://github.com/atlimited/cat2vec) and an [example (based on Word2Vec)](https://www.kaggle.com/classtag/cat2vec-powerful-feature-for-categorical) in Kaggle, and this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.00979) for the latter and its [implementation](https://github.com/dirty-cat/dirty_cat). The idea of the former is to convert categories to vectors. As much as I have to say it really make sense to work, but I have no experience using it. The latter, so-called *dirty_cat*, looks quite promising and easy to use. Whether it is robust to having unseen cardinal category in your test data is not clear to me!

P.S.: I would like to add that the idea of city to a geographical location given in the first comment is really nice and it is actually not complicated as they are many Python API e.g. by Google or HERE that allows you to do that. But it is noted that this is just a way to engineer new features and certainly not to be replaced by the city feature itself.

Interesting references to check [first](http://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html), [second](https://medium.com/data-design/visiting-categorical-features-and-encoding-in-decision-trees-53400fa65931), [third](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-feature-engineering-part-2-categorical-data-f54324193e63), [fourth](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/categorical-data) (no particular order!)

All above-mentioned points are practical solutions rather concretely theoretically correct, and surely subject to further discussions. And I am more than happy to learn more.

Comment: What about creating clustering of similar cities? Like even if we have a new city, it's isn't different than what all we already have, we can cross-check with the closest matching city?

Comment: Pleasure Aditya. That is also another excellent idea. I do not know about the new "Similarity Encoding", it might be case they are doing exactly the same thing. Check their tutorial. Also a side note that one has to be be careful what clustering to use for categorical data like k-modes, after all their distances do not have similar meaning as numerical values.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. How could I do the retrain? I mean, imagine I have a new candidate and I want to predict wether he/she is good or bad, how could I retrain my model if I don't have his/her true label indicating if it's good or not? I don't see the way to include this new data to do the retraining and I will be missing the point of prediction. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are welcome. About retraining: it literally means to start over, mix all all your data making sure you have new data in and start learning again. The other point you mentioned that you don't have the true label for that particular new data point: this is very different story for itself. What you could do to label this data point is looking that most similar datapoint and take the label from there like the very simple KNN algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing to do (which is usually a good place to start) is just one-hot-encode your cities where every city becomes a single feature and has values of either 1 (the person is from that city) or 0 (not from that city). If a new city appears in a test set that isn't present in the training set that person will just have 0's for all the cities in the training set. This might seem weird but, if that city isn't in the training set, then there should be no weight placed a person being from that city.

The next step would be something along the lines of what Mohammad Athar suggested and get some idea of geographic proximity to other cities in your training set. That is going to be much more complicated so I will let someone else comment on it.

Comment: Starting simple and growing from there is a great advice!

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [Vowpal Wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki), which handles very nicely new features using a [hashing trick](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Feature-Hashing-and-Extraction) and adaptive learning rates.

Not only will it not crash when new features appear (at train or test time), it will also start updating its weights on it. On top of that its wicked fast. It only implements variants of the linear model though, so you are restricted on that side. A very powerful tool to know about